# How to measure quality of a split for numeric values?

Tags: anova, factor-analysis, cart

I have a big set of real numbers. Each number comes with a list of associated attributes (some of them are numeric, others are categorical). For example, to make it less abstract, I have income of different persons and each person comes with such attributes as age, gender, country, height, weight and so on.

Now I would like to find an attribute and its value that provides the "best split". For example, I can use age and value 36 for the split. In this case all the persons that have age smaller or equal to 36 go to the first set and all the others go to the second one. In case of a nominal variable, for example country, all persons that correspond to a given value of a country (for example USA) go to one set and all the other persons go to the second set.

I have many different alternative splits and I would like to find the best one (in terms of the income). I have different ideas how it can be done.

For example I can use absolute difference between the means of the incomes corresponding to the two sets. The larger is this difference, the better is the split.

Alternatively, I can calculate variance for each set and use the sum of the two variances as the measure. The smaller this measure is, the better is the split.

Both approaches, have a disadvantage: They do not take into account the sizes of the sets. I think that a split is not good is one of the sets contains 3 person and another one 99997.

One of the formulas that I found is:

$\frac{n1}{n2} \cdot v_1 + (1 - \frac{n1}{n2}) \cdot v_2,$

where $v_i$ are variances of the two sets and $n_i$ are their sizes. Is it really the beast measure of the quality of the split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One natural candidate would be using the residual sum of squares. Thus, you would take the mean in each subsample and sum the squared deviations from it. This directly corresponds to what is done in an ANOVA. Also, it takes the sample size into account because you take the sum (rather than the corresponding mean).